# How can I run a Xamarin.UITest from the commandline?

Tags: testing, xamarin, teamcity, xamarin.uitest

I would like to run tests (made using Xamarin.UITest) on my build server, which runs TeamCity on OS X.

I have searched online on how to do this, but I am only able to find how these tests can be submitted to Xamarin Test Cloud. This is not what I want, I want to run the tests I wrote directly on devices (and/or simulators) connected to the build server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

according to the [docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/cheatsheet/#Running_UITests_Using_the_Command_Line) (requires NUnit 2.6.3)

```
$ mono <path-to>/Nunit-2.6.3/bin/nunit-console.exe <path/to/uitest-assembly.dll>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I do on OS-X:

- Locally install the correct `nunit-console.exe` version
- Build the app
- Build the uitests
- Run the tests

Example:

```
nuget install NUnit.Runners -Version 2.6.4
xbuild iOS/UITestFromCmdLine.iOS.csproj /target:Build
xbuild UITests/UITestFromCmdLine.UITests.csproj
mono ./NUnit.Runners.2.6.4/tools/nunit-console.exe UITests/bin/Debug/UITestFromCmdLine.UITests.dll
```