# MSB4019 Run Xamarin Android Unit Tests using Github Actions

Tags: shell, unit-testing, xamarin.android, mono, github-actions

Need to run Xamarin.Android specific Unit Tests using Github Actions. Everything builds OK, but when I trying to `dotnet test` got the following error:

error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.300\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.300\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

My script is:

```
 - name: UnitTests.Droid
      run: |
        dotnet restore
        nuget restore
        cd MobileAccess.UnitTests.Droid
        msbuild MobileAccess.UnitTests.Droid.csproj /verbosity:normal /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release
        dotnet test
```

P.S. Solution-specific Unit Tests that do not affect Android run correctly

Comment: `dotnet` command is strictly for .NET Core projects today (.NET 5 will change that), so run the actual command line test tool instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37792674/how-can-i-run-a-xamarin-uitest-from-the-commandline

Comment: @Lex Li I do not understand what exactly should I write instead of dotnet test because I am new one in this. XUnit in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was ably to run droid-specific unit tests in xamarin using:

```
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - uses: nuget/setup-nuget@v1
    - uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.0.0  
    - name: UnitTests.Droid
      run: |
        nuget restore
        cd YourDroidUnitTestsCsprojDirectory
        msbuild YourDroidUnitTestsCsproj.csproj /verbosity:normal /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release

    - name: Setup VSTest.exe
      uses: Malcolmnixon/Setup-VSTest@v3

    - name: VSTest
      run: |
        cd YourDroidUnitTestsDirectory
        cd bin
        cd Release
        cd netcoreapp3.0
        ls
        vstest.console MobileAccess.UnitTests.Droid.dll
```